# How to make blocks line up side-by-side in pairs?

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of simple divs with content in them, they are 50% width and float left. This means that they all line up side by side (in pairs). However, if one of the blocks has less content than the other, the block underneath floats on the wrong side = breaks.

Is there a simple/clean way to deal with this problem that doesn't involve adding clearfix divs after every second div?
this is the css code as it is now:

```
div {width:50%; background:#ccc; float:left; margin-bottom:20px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yWxBe/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```css
div:nth-child(odd){
  clear: left;
}
```

Here's your demo updated: http://jsfiddle.net/yWxBe/1/

Comment: And / Or add this declaration, for example, to a `.clear` `class` on the respective `div`'s for legacy browsers.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you Bill. @YaMo, I don't quite understand what you mean, are you saying that legacy browsers won't read :nth-child(odd)?

Comment: @user2413333 [Yes I am, IE8 and below](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: legacy browsers = old browsers, ie8 and under will need the clear class

Comment: It works in IE9+. You can use a plugin like http://selectivizr.com/ to get it working in older browsers. He was suggesting adding a class called "clear" to every odd element and using `.clear { clear: left; }`. If you're using jQuery you can do like `$('div:nth-child(odd)').css('clear', 'left')`

Answer (score 0):

You can make to container divs for the right and left column?

Alternative: jQuery, there are tons of jQuery-libraries for this problem.